# React redux - Why do I get state.bookmarkedRecipes is not iterable?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

trying to save in local storage bookmarked recipes but i keep getting  state.bookmarkedRecipes is not iterable what I am doing wrong?  Please help me!!

**redux store**

```
 const reducer = combineReducers({
  recipeList: recipeListReducer,
  recipeDetail: recipeDetailsReducer,
  bookmark: bookmarkReducer,
});

const bookmarkedRecipesFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("bookmarkedRecipes")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarkedRecipes"))
  : [];

const initialState = {
     bookmark:{
bookmarkedRecipes: bookmarkedRecipesFromStorage,
    };
}
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

**bookmarkReducer**
The payload which is the new bookmarked recipe will be added to the bookmarkedRecipes that was saved in the localStorage.

```
    export const bookmarkReducer = (state = { bookmarkedRecipes: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BOOKMARK_ADD_RECIPE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        bookmarkedRecipes: [...state.bookmarkedRecipes, action.payload],
      };
    }

    default:
      return { state };
  }
};
```

**bookmarkAction**
This is what the action looks like with the passed id it will get the recipe from the api and pass it as a payload with only the properties below.

```
export const addBookmark = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/get?rId=${id}`
  );

  console.log(data.recipe);

  dispatch({
    type: BOOKMARK_ADD_RECIPE,
    payload: {
      recipe: data.recipe.recipe_id,
      title: data.recipe.title,
    },
  });
    localStorage.setItem(
      "bookmarkedRecipes",JSON.stringify(getState().bookmark.bookmarkedRecipes)
    );
};
```

Comment: I suspect the error is *actually* in your reducer where you are spreading `bookmarkedRecipes` into a new array reference, but nothing is jumping at me currently. Can you rule one or the other by first commenting out the `BOOKMARK_ADD_RECIPE` action dispatch, and then the `localStorage.setItem` call, to see which is causing the error?

Comment: Hi tried what you said now I'm getting this type of error:
 Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: And which code is causing that? Which is/was commented out?

Comment: Somehow at the Redux store code:

const bookmarkedRecipesFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("bookmarkedRecipes")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarkedRecipes"))
  : [];
gives me this ERROR: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

then when i commented out the BOOKMARK_ADD_RECIPE action dispatch: 
state.bookmarkedRecipes is not iterable ERROR went away

Comment: Looks like you are getting malformed JSON along the line somewhere. Maybe check that `getState().bookmark.bookmarkedRecipes` is the value you expect it to be before it's stringified and shoved in localStorage. You can split out the logic a bit and get the `JSON.stringify(getState().bookmark.bookmarkedRecipes)` value and run it through an online JSON validator as a sanity check. Or post here in your question so other have better context.

Comment: Why is it when I console.log (state.bookmarkedRecipe) in bookmarkReducer in returns undefined despite having an item returned when i  console.log(getState().bookmark.bookmarkedRecipes) in bookmarkAction?

Comment: Is it because your state is `state.bookmarkedRecipes`? Plural, with an "s"? Do you think you could try creating a *running* codesandbox minimal example that reproduces this issue that we could live debug?